# Pesach circumcision a rememberance of the covenant made with Avraham?

Tags: passover, korban, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, brit-milah, abraham

Within the narrative of the story of the covenant and promise made with Avraham we learn a couple of things. One of those things is that the seed of Avraham will be gerim in a land not theirs. It's part of the story in which a covenant is established and promises are made. Another point is that Avraham and his whole household get circumcised.

At the Pesach the Pesach meal is kept within a household and all the male needed to be circumcised.

It was because HaShem remembered his covenant at the beginning of the story and the note afterwards that is was 400 and 30 years, to that day, that HaShem brought the Israelites up out from Egypt that I begane to wonder if there were any commentaries on the connection of circumcision of the Pesach with that of Avraham, if the circumcision at the Pesach was part of a commemoration to the promise and covenant made with Avraham?

Comment: The circumcision command comes with the covenant in Genesis 17. The 430 years' strangerhood comes with the covenant in Genesis 15. That seems to weaken your proposal considerably.

Comment: @msh210 What about the promise of the land and that HaShem would be a Elohim forever to the ofspring of Avraham in both occasions. You seem to talk about two different things but isn't the covenant of Gen 17 just an exstencion of the one made in 15 which is also an exstencion of Gen 12? There are so many similarities, and so much is being foretold within these regarding the Exodus and the Land the ofspring is to be brought to.

Comment: @msh210 I found this statement on: https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/passover-from-the-bible-to-the-temples/  "Non-Israelites and uncircumcised ones were precluded from participating in the feast of the paschal lamb because the occasion was one of reaffirming G-d’s covenant with the Israelites. The symbolism of the eating of the paschal lamb with the matzah and bitter herbs was a reminder to the Israelites of an enslaved past." But I can't figure out if this is truly a Jewish website.